React native pod file use_modular_headers! throwing Redefinition of module 'ReactCommon' error

I have created a sample react native project npx react-native init MyNewProject
I added pod dependency in ios pod file
I added use_modular_headers!
Getting error as  Redefinition of module 'ReactCommon' error in xcode project
in vs code getting below error


target 'MyNewProject' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  pod 'some pod'

  target 'MyNewProjectTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

I tried pod uninstall and install

Please post the an error as text, not a screenshot.

I opened a bug report for this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/45000

I had the same issue with other pods (Firebase). I assume the issue has to do with recursive dependecnies that are also imported explicitly. I tried all the same things as you did, although the only thing that helped me was to close xcode, run
pod deintegrate
pod install

and rebuild.
In you have installed firebase recently, try this:
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

